# Lark parser can't parse characters, even though they are defined in regex of rule

Tags: python, regex, lark-parser

I'm trying to write a SMTP parser and took some information for quoted strings from the [rfc](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-4.1.2). So I have the following grammar (taken out all the parts that work, focusing on the thing that doesn't):

```
quoted_string  : /[\x22]/ qcontentsmtp* /[\x22]/
qcontentsmtp   : qtextsmtp | quoted_pairsmtp
quoted_pairsmtp  : /[\x5C\x5C]/ /[\x20-\x7E]/
qtextsmtp      : /[\x20-\x21|\x23-\x5B|\x5D-\x7E]/

command : [ quoted_string ]
```

With the only `start` for the parser being the `command`-rule.

When I input `"quoted_string"`, I would expect it to be parsed as such:

```
command -> quoted_string -> qcontentsmtp -> qtextsmtp
```

As you can see, `qtextsmtp` contains alphanumeric characters, coded as a regex, as shown in the rfc. However, when I try to parse it, I get this message:

```
input = '"quoted_string"'
....
####### Parsing Failed
No terminal defined for 'q' at line 1 col 2

"quoted_string"
 ^
```

when I input just `""` it works as expected.

When I change the rule `qtextsmtp` and exchange the regex for `"a"` and make the input be `'"a"'` it also works.

I defined all the rules as functions in my transformer, very basic, like so:

```
class StringsTransformer(Transformer):
# externals
def quoted_string(self, args):
    return "".join(args)

# internals
def qcontentsmtp(self, args):
    return "".join(args)

def quoted_pairsmtp(self, args):
    return "".join(args)

def qtextsmtp(self, args):
    return "".join(args)
```

But I don't even get to those rules because, as I said, it won't even parse.

I'm not quite sure why the regex doesn't work. I use these type of rules in other parts and they work just fine, just with this one it doesn't.

Comment: what does the forward slash mean in your grammar? another example where I've seen it is in the following `/.*?/`. In your in the `/[\x22]/ qcontentsmtp* /[\x22]/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like Lark's regexp parser is confused with the quoting of `[` and `]` as `\x5b` and `\x5d` respectively, and the `q` letter simply doesn't match the regexp. After replacing `\x5b` with `\[` and `\x5d` with `\]`, the grammar parses the provided input, as shown by the following program:

```
import lark

grammar = r"""
quoted_string  : /[\x22]/ qcontentsmtp* /[\x22]/
qcontentsmtp   : qtextsmtp | quoted_pairsmtp
quoted_pairsmtp  : /[\x5C\x5C]/ /[\x20-\x7E]/
qtextsmtp      : /[\x20-\x21\x23-\[\]-\x7E]/

command : [ quoted_string ]
"""

parser = lark.Lark(grammar, start='command')

print(parser.parse('"quoted_string"'))
```

(Note that `|` is superfluous in character sets, it is interpreted as just another character to match.)

This is not a general limitation of Python regexps, which are perfectly capable of accepting `[` and `]` escaped in hex:

```
>>> re.compile(r'[\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7e]').match('q')
<re.Match object; span=(0, 1), match='q'>
```

I've now [reported the issue](https://github.com/lark-parser/lark/issues/474) to the maintainers of Lark.

Comment: Works beautifully! And thank you for reporting the issue. As you stated there, I did expect the hex code to be escaped and I 100% support the notion that this is a usability issue.

Comment: what does the forward slash mean in your grammar? another example where I've seen it is in the following `/.*?/`. In your in the `/[\x22]/ qcontentsmtp* /[\x22]/`.

Comment: @CharlieParker It's a Lark thing, `/.../` terminals contain regular expressions. See [the docs here](https://lark-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/grammar.html#terminals).

Comment: thanks! I did see the docs but it didn't explicitly say thats what it meant plus there was a random + sign e.g. `/regular expression+/` which personally really threw me off. Confirmation is nice I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using string literals in terminals if you can; even though they won't match the RFC identically, they certainly work in the existing lark parser implementation. (Your example fails for me too, but using the below works. Not sure I understand the underpinnings as to *why*.)

```
DOUBLE_QUOTED_STRING  : /"[^"]*"/
```

reference from [the lark src](https://github.com/lark-parser/lark/blob/f43631949cddf6a50fa1bb5d083335b2c6eefee8/tests/test_parser.py#L882).

How are you defining your grammar? You may need to escape your `\` backslashes, if you are defining it inline in your code (vs reading from a file).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As I said in my question, I would really like for my lark parser to match the RFC as much as possible. I already had to change some parts and would really like to keep that to a minimum. As it turns out however, doing that in this case is not necessarily possible. Please check out [the above answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58784184/4687402)

Comment: what does the forward slash mean in your grammar? another example where I've seen it is in the following `/.*?/`.

Comment: This represents a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), which is a general grammar for string-matching (specifically, for string-matching of regular languages... But that's maybe in the weeds here!)